# else if statement doesn't work when i put it in while loop

Tags: java

I have a problem, when I use if statement in while loop, it works with if, but it doesn't in else if

I need from program to print the largest number and the second largest number

here is the code

```
int num = S.nextInt();
int max = num;
int max2 = num;
while (num != -1) {
    if (num > max)
        max = num;

    else if (max2 <= num && max > num)
        max2 = num;

num = S.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("The max = " + max);
System.out.print("The max 2 = " + max2 );
```

Comment: hello, first I want to ask you, what is ```S``` in ```S.nextInt()``` ?

Comment: @JabalLogian Probably a Scanner

Comment: Yes it's Scanner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not the problem why not go into else if.it's logic problem.
I can show you example

```java
int num = S.nextInt();
int max = num;
int max2 = 0;
while (num != -1) {
    if (num > max){
        max2 = max;
        max = num;
    }else if (num > max2){
        max2 = num;
    }

    num = S.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("The max = " + max);
System.out.print("The max 2 = " + max2 );
```

the solution is

- if max find bigger number.then give original max number to max2.and the new number to max
- in case the first num is the biggest.so we set max2 to 0.and if there is no bigger number than max,we do compare on max2

Comment: Good answer, One quibble: stylistically, it's inconsistent to write `num > max` and then `max2 < num`. (I know this came from the OP).  The  second should be written `num > max2` to make the code more obvious.

Comment: yes thank you it works now.
but what about we delete else if? I think it will work fine

Comment: @iggy thanks.I update my code,make the code more clear.@Nawaf.112 We can not delete `else if`,I talk about it below the code,in case the first number is the biggest number.

Comment: @Nawaf.112  Consider the sequence 6 5 4.  Without the 'else if', max2 will never change from zero.